# MySQL Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'users'

Tags: mysql

I am facing difficulties to join three tables. And then joining the third table two times to get user information

I have a table called `teams` and in this table, I have `playerOneId` and `playerTwoId`. These id s are actually from `users` table so I also want to get both the players information from the users table. So here I tried a query

```
    select 
    `clubteams`.`id`, `clubteams`.`className`, `clubteams`.`que`, 
    `teams`.`id`, `teams`.`teamName`, `teams`.`playerOneId`, `teams`.`playerTwoId`,
    `users`.`firstName`, `users`.`lastName`, `users`.`email`, `users`.`phone` 
    from `teams` 
    inner join `clubteams` on `teams`.`id` = `clubteams`.`team_id` 
    inner join `users` on `teams`.`playerOneId` = `users`.`id` 
    inner join `users` on `teams`.`playerTwoId` = `users`.`id` 
    where `clubteams`.`club_id` = 9 and `clubteams`.`isTemporary` = 1
```

Here note that two joins with users table

```
inner join `users` on `teams`.`playerOneId` = `users`.`id` 
inner join `users` on `teams`.`playerTwoId` = `users`.`id`
```

how can I get both players information using playerOneId and playerTwoId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alias the user tables u1 and u2 to resolve the error.

```
inner join `users` u1 on `teams`.`playerOneId` = u1.`id` 
inner join `users` u2 on `teams`.`playerTwoId` =  u2.`id`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aliases instead of full table names. Also, no need for backticks unless you use reserved words.

```
select 
    ct.id, 
    ct.className, 
    ct.que, 
    t.id, 
    t.teamName, 
    t.playerOneId, 
    t.playerTwoId,
    u2.firstName, 
    u2.lastName, 
    u2.email, 
    u2.phone 
from teams t
    inner join clubteams ct on t.id = ct.team_id 
    inner join users u1 on t.playerOneId = u1.id 
    inner join users u2 on t.playerTwoId = u2.id 
where ct.club_id = 9 and ct.isTemporary = 1
```